# Chef - unable to set vmswappiness in cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to set up vm.swappiness in the sysctl.conf file.  I have included sysctl in the metadb.rb file yet the chef-client run does not effect the change.  Please help. 
      This is what i have in the recipe...... 
      node.set['sysctl']['set swappiness'] = { 'vm.swappiness' => '0' }

Comment: https://github.com/svanzoest-cookbooks/sysctl/blob/master/templates/default/sysctl.conf.erb

Comment: My sysctl cookbook already has this patch.  I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked.  Somehow the recipe required the include_recipe:sysctl to be explicitly set even though I had it set in the metadata.rb.

```
include_recipe 'sysctl::default'
include_recipe 'sysctl::apply'
node.default['sysctl']['params']['vm']['swappiness'] =  '0'
```

Comment: That's correct. The "depends" statement in the metadata loads the cookbook into scope, it doesn't add it to the run-list.